# cannot cast from List to EntityCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to update an entityCollection

Here is my linq:

```
itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1 = 
                (EntityCollection<MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1>) itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1
                                             .Select(browserEfItem =>
                                                     FillFromUi(browserEfItem,
                                                                item.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1
                                                                .Single(browserUiItem => browserUiItem.BrowserVersionId == browserEfItem.BrowserVersionId)))
                                                                .ToList().AsEnumerable();
```

However I get a runtime casting error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Conduit.Mam.MaMDBEntityFramework.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1]'
>   to type
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[Conduit.Mam.MaMDBEntityFramework.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1]'.

Why is that? As I'm doing linq to entity, no?

Comment: I have no experience with EntityCollection itself but i'd guess you need to do "new EntityCollection<MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1>(...)" instead of casting, where ... is your linq expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `List<MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1>` with your second-last call `ToList()` in your Linq expression and then you try to cast this list to an `EntityCollection<MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1`. I would recommend to create a new `EntityCollection` and add the results from the LINQ query to this collection, like so:

```
var collection = new EntityCollection<MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1>();
var processedItems = itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1
                                         .Select(browserEfItem =>
                                                 FillFromUi(browserEfItem,
                                                            item.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1
                                                            .Single(browserUiItem => browserUiItem.BrowserVersionId == browserEfItem.BrowserVersionId)))
                                                            .ToList();
foreach(var item in processedItems)
{
    collection.Add(item);
}
```

**Important:** your code seems to mix database concerns with business logic and personally I never used an `EntityCollect<T>` directly in my code. I don't know your context but maybe you should consider using the Repository and Unit of Work pattern. Search for them on Google.

Answer (score 0):

ItemFromDB is an unique object? I mean that if itemFromDB is not a list, yo are trying to convert a unique object to a list.

instead of .ToList().AsEnumerable() you can try to use .FirstOrDefault().